# ORACLE UPDATE SAME TABLE

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I am getting error while updating one set of data by applying condition (LESS THAN SYMBOL) with other set of data on same table. could someone please help me.

Below is my oracle query -

```
UPDATE TABLE 
   SET COLUMN1 = 1 
 WHERE COLUMN2 = 'Y' 
   AND COLUMN3 = 'N' 
   AND TRUNC(COLUMN4)  <
       (SELECT TRUNC(COLUMN4) 
          FROM TABLE 
         WHERE COLUMN3 = 'Y' AND COLUMN4 = 'Y')
```

ERROR AS BELOW  -

> SQL Error:
>
> **ORA-01427**: single-row subquery returns more than one row
>   01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: What does `< (set of data)` mean in this case?

Comment: @BobJarvis - or in *any* case for that matter?

Answer (score 2):

First some *homework*; please do not call your table `TABLE` (Oracle will complain). Additionally your subquery doesn't make sense:

```
(SELECT TRUNC(COLUMN4) 
          FROM TABLE 
         WHERE COLUMN3 = 'Y' AND COLUMN4 = 'Y')
```

If `COLUMN4 = 'Y` what does `TRUNC(COLUMN4)` mean?

But I guess what you mean is this (sample data added)

```
create table TAB  as
select 1  COLUMN1, 'Y' COLUMN2, 'N' COLUMN3, sysdate-1 COLUMN4 from dual union all
select 2  COLUMN1, 'Y' COLUMN2, 'Y' COLUMN3, sysdate COLUMN4 from dual union all
select 2  COLUMN1, 'Y' COLUMN2, 'Y' COLUMN3, sysdate COLUMN4 from dual;

UPDATE TAB  
   SET COLUMN1 = 1 
 WHERE COLUMN2 = 'Y' 
   AND COLUMN3 = 'N' 
   AND TRUNC(COLUMN4)  <
       (SELECT TRUNC(COLUMN4) 
          FROM TAB  
         WHERE COLUMN2 = 'Y' AND COLUMN3 = 'Y');
```

Which leads to

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

The **problem** is, with `<`  you can compare only two numbers, if you want to compare a number with a *set of numbers* (= result of a subquery with more rows), you must use the [**Group Comparison Conditions**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions002.htm#SQLRF52110). Two choices are available:

**< ALL** - the predicate is valid for **ALL** values returned by the subquery

**< ANY / < SOME** the predicate is valid for **SOME** (at least one) value returned by the subquery .

So what you can do this for example

```
UPDATE TAB  
   SET COLUMN1 = 1 
 WHERE COLUMN2 = 'Y' 
   AND COLUMN3 = 'N' 
   AND TRUNC(COLUMN4)  < ALL
       (SELECT TRUNC(COLUMN4) 
          FROM TAB  
         WHERE COLUMN2 = 'Y' AND COLUMN3 = 'Y');
```

Update will be done in rows with `TRUNC(COLUMN4)` *less than* **ALL* values returned by the subquery.

Comment: **< ALL** and **< ANY** are not the only options (these correspond, roughly, to **< MIN** and **< MAX**, respectively). Often **< AVG** is a meaningful condition, and there are others as well.

Comment: @mathguy, thanks for pointing that out. Please provide a link to the documentation of those features.

Comment: A link to what? To aggregate functions? You surely are familiar with them. :-)

Comment: @mathguy I missing a link to [Group Comparison Conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions002.htm#SQLRF52110) other than `< ALL, < ANY, < SOME`. I.e. a predicate comparing an `expression` with a `result of  subquery (with more than one row)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the message is pretty clear.  Perhaps you should use an aggregation function:

```
UPDATE TABLE 
   SET COLUMN1 = 1 
WHERE COLUMN2 = 'Y' AND
      COLUMN3 = 'N' AND
      TRUNC(COLUMN4) < (SELECT MIN(TRUNC(COLUMN4))
                        FROM TABLE 
                        WHERE COLUMN3 = 'Y' AND COLUMN4 = 'Y'
                       );
```

EDIT:

Given the columns you've specified, this could be simplified to:

```
UPDATE TABLE 
   SET COLUMN1 = 1 
WHERE COLUMN2 = 'Y' AND
      COLUMN3 = 'N' AND
      TRUNC(COLUMN4) < 'Y';
```

You might need an additional condition, if the purpose of the subquery was to see if any rows exist.

Comment: What would `TRUNC(COLUMN4) < 'Y'` even mean? Not helpful.